# Почему при отладке программы в gdb выполнение идёт скачками?

Tags: c++, gdb

В gdb ввожу команду next и прыгаю на 100 строку, потом на 97 потом на 100 потом на 97 потом на 100 потом на 103. Не ну понять почему с 97 на 100 можно. На 98 и 99 объявляются новые переменные, но почему скочки по 97 и 100, и таже картина со 102 и 104 я не понимаю. В чём проблема?

Comment: Объявления переменных без инициализации не порождают никакого кода. Поэтому отладчик через них и "прыгает".

Comment: А вы уверены, что программа у вас собрана не в релизном варианте (т.е. без оптимизаций),

Comment: А как выключить оптимизации. Компилятор стандартный gcc

Comment: `-O0 -g` (что бы и оптимизаций не было, и отладочная информация)

Comment: @Andru, передать ключ `-O0`, **вместо** какогого-нить `-O{1,2,3}`.

Comment: скачек с 100 на 97 - это отрабатывает деструктор скорее всего.

Answer (score 0):

Одна C/C++ строка может состоять из нескольких ассемблерных команд. Каждой ассемблерной инструкции (если используется опция -g) приписана ссылка на файл и номер строки. Компилятор в процессе оптимизаций может менять порядок ассемблерных инструкций, в том числе, перемешивая инструкции из разных строчек (и даже файлов, если были инлайны функций). Скорее всего в gdb команда next останавливается, как только начался новый диапазон (файл + строка). Если диапазоны частично перемешены, то создается впечатление скачков по исходникам.
  Другими словами использование "-g" вместе с "-O2" не дает простого способа привязки текущих инструкций к исходникам. Нормально такая привязка работает только на "-g -O0".

P.S. Кроме команды next есть еще команды nexti/stepi и disas, но это команды уже пошагового исполнения ассемблерных инструкций.